# Unit Tests for FLASK API

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I have a basic flask API running :

```py
u/app.route('/helloworld', methods = ['GET'])
def first_api():
    hname = "hello"
    lhname = "world"
    print(hname+lhanme)
```

Now I need to add some unit tests to it, and here is my unit test file:

```py
import json
def test_index(app, client):
    res = client.get('/helloworld')
    assert res.status_code == 200
    assert "hello" in res.data
```

How can I pass value for variables `hname` and `lhname` from this unit test?

Here is my `conf` file for `pytest`:

```py
import pytest
from app import app as flask_app
u/pytest.fixture
def app():
    return flask_app

u/pytest.fixture

def client(app):
    return app.test_client()
```

Comment: Hi! Please consider edit your post to use blocks of code and format it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

You have a little mistake in your endpoint. You want it to return the string instead of printing it. Please consider the following example:

```
from flask import Flask, request

flask_app = Flask(__name__)
app = flask_app

@app.route('/helloworld', methods = ['GET'])
def first_api():
    hname = request.args.get("hname")
    lhname = request.args.get("lname")
    print(hname)
    return hname + lhname



def test_index(app):
    client = app.test_client()
    hname = "hello"
    lname = "world"
    res = client.get('/helloworld?hname={}&lname={}'.format(hname, lname))
    assert res.status_code == 200
    assert "hello" in res.data.decode("UTF-8")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_index(app)
```

Comment: But, My question is how can i pass a variable to over-write the hname and lhanme variables in my flask app

Comment: Well okay, but your question then has nothing to do with testing. You´re asking about the behaviour of flask endpoints. I´ll edit my answer to point this out as well.

Comment: @Legitimate_Figure_4430 I´ll recommend you to have a look at the flask documentation :)

Comment: I think there is some confusion :). My question is related to testing because I want to create unit tests for my flask app and over-write the variable in my flask app from the unit test.

Comment: @Legitimate_Figure_4430 Okay, answer me one question please. What do you want to achieve?